# why is ++ overloaded but not -- for c++ bool

Tags: c++, c, boolean, operator-overloading

I am trying to figure out why I can `++b` a bool but not `--b` it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    bool b = false;
    ++b;
    --b; // error C2428: '--' : not allowed on operand of type 'bool'

    printf("%s %d", b ? "true" : "false", b);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got a warning: `incrementing expression of type bool is deprecated`.

Comment: You should probably specify your compiler in this case.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart any compiler should do it, the behaviour (including a warning, as the old practice it's for compatibility with wasn't a good one) is mandated by the standard.